# Nested dictionary with dataframes to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I know that there are a few questions about nested dictionaries to dataframe but their solutions do not work for me. I have a dataframe, which is contained in a dictionary, which is contained in another dictionary, like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'2019-01-01':[38],'2019-01-02':[43]},index = [1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'2019-01-01':[108],'2019-01-02':[313]},index = [1,2])
da = {}
da['ES']={}
da['ES']['TV']=df1
da['ES']['WEB']=df2
```

What I want to obtain is the following:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'market':['ES','ES','ES','ES'],'device':['TV','TV','WEB','WEB'],
                     'ds':['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-01','2019-01-02'],
                     'yhat':[43,38,423,138]})
```

Getting the code from another SO question I have tried this:

```
market_ids = []
frames = []
for market_id,d in da.items():
  market_ids.append(market_id)
  frames.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(da,orient = 'index'))    
df = pd.concat(frames, keys=market_ids)
```

Which gives me a dataframe with multiple indexes and the devices as column names.

Thank you

Comment: Okay, I get your question, and I think it should be that difficult.

Wait, I am working on it

So just correct me if I am wrong. That df_final is how you want your dataframe to look like and da above is how you have the values available... right?

Comment: That is exactly right

Comment: See I am able to get the output, and it's working well. Though I am not sure how will you implement that in your actual data. Because to apply it under a loop, I need good amount of actual data(or some changed value) to work on. But still, I'll share what I got and if that makes any useful sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works well and gives the desired output:

```
t1=da['ES']['TV'].melt(var_name='ds', value_name='yhat')
t1['market']='ES'
t1['device']='TV'

t2=da['ES']['WEB'].melt(var_name='ds', value_name='yhat')
t2['market']='ES'
t2['device']='WEB'

m = pd.concat([t1,t2]).reset_index().drop(columns={'index'})

print(m)
```

And the output is:

```
           ds  yhat market device
0  2019-01-01    38     ES     TV
1  2019-01-02    43     ES     TV
2  2019-01-01   108     ES    WEB
3  2019-01-02   313     ES    WEB
```

The main takeaway here is melt function, which if you read about isn't that difficult to understand what's it doing here. Now as I mentioned in the comment above, this can be done iteratively over whole da named dictionary, but to perform that I'd need replicated form of the actual data. What I intended to do was to take this first t1 as the initial dataframe and then keep on concatinating others to it, which should be really easy. But I don't know how your actual values are. But I am sure you can figure out on your own from above how to put this under a loop.

The pseudo code for that loop thing I am talking about would be like this:

```
real=t1
for a in da['ES'].keys():
    if a!='TV':

        p=da['ES'][a].melt(var_name='ds', value_name='yhat')
        p['market']='ES'
        p['device']=a

        real = pd.concat([real,p],axis=0,sort=True)

real.reset_index().drop(columns={'index'})
```